# writing an arraylist to file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, printwriter

I'm having some trouble writing an array list to file using printwriter. I've tried another way that worked but it wouldn't print all the things from the array list just one. This is the way I'm trying at the moment and it won't print anything.

```
datArrayList = new ArrayList<theAccounts>();
File file = new File("output.txt");

public void writer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{ 


   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
   FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
   int datList = datArrayList.size();

   for (int i = 0; i < datList; i++){
    pw.write(datArrayList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
  }
```

Can anyone tell me what i should be doing to write all the items in the array to the output file? thank you :)

Comment: To write objects to a file, you should consider serializing instead of text.

Comment: You're opening two FileOutputStreams for the same file, and using only one of them. Remove the one that you aren't using.

Comment: Code you posted is incomplete. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `close()` your streams, or use a [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Comment: Are there any objects in the datArrayList???

Answer (score 2):

Possibly because you weren't closing your streams, try:

```
datArrayList = new ArrayList<theAccounts>();
File file = new File("output.txt");

   public void writer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
       try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file))){
           int datList = datArrayList.size();

           for (theAccounts s : datArrayList){
               pw.println(s);
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: `fo` is unused, and closing `pw` should be done in a `finally` block or with try-with-resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
datArrayList = new ArrayList<theAccounts>();
File file = new File("output.txt");

public void writer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
   FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fo);
   int datList = datArrayList.size();

   for (theAccounts elem : datArrayList){
       pw.println(elem);
   }
   pw.close();
   fo.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that works. Need to flush/close streams  in finally block.

```
package com.sto.sanbox;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Accounts {

    public class Account {

        String name;
        String amount;

        public Account(String name, String amount) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public void setAmount(String amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return this.getName() + ", " + this.getAmount();
        }

    }

    public  void writer(ArrayList<Account> datArrayList) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = null;
        FileOutputStream fo = null;
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = new File("output.txt");
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
            fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            int datList = datArrayList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < datList; i++) {
                pw.write(datArrayList.get(i).toString() + "\n");
            }
        } finally {
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            fo.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Accounts Writer = new Accounts();
        ArrayList<Account> datArrayList = new ArrayList<Account>();
        Account account = Writer.new Account(" Name" , " 100000");
        datArrayList.add(account);

        try {
            Writer.writer(datArrayList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things to consider:

- Closing your `PrintWriter`
- Not making a second `FileOutputStream` called `fo` since this is unneeded
- Making sure you're creating your file output.txt via `file.newFile()`